# Erro em consulta

Tags: php, mysql

O que está errado?

Eu fiz tudo certo, pesquisei e me retonra o erro:

> ```
> Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\tipo\consulta-online.php on line 21
> ```

O que pode ser?

```
<?php

    $servidorBanco = "localhost";
    $usuarioBanco = "root";
    $senhaBanco = "12345";
    $dadosBanco = "bancodedados";

    $conexao = mysqli_connect($servidorBanco, $usuarioBanco, $senhaBanco, $dadosBanco);

    if(!$conexao){
        die("Falha na conexao: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }else{
        //echo "Conexao realizada com sucesso";
    }   

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sis_clientes";
    $result = $conexao->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

           //É isso que eu quero que consulta, quero que consulte 
           //todos os dados refere a esse campo da tabela "login"
           echo $row["login"];

        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conexao->close();
?>
```

Comment: Verifique se a tabela realmente existe. Caso exista, adicione um `die($conexao->error);` após `$conexao->query`.

Comment: Deu esse erro. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'die' (T_EXIT) in C:\xampp\htdocs\tipo\consulta-online.php on line 17

Comment: eu fiz dessa maneira. $result = $conexao->query($sql) die($conexao->error);

Comment: E tbm tentei assim. $result = $conexao->query($sql); $result = $conexao->error; Tambem sem resultados.

Comment: Faltou o **or**. O correto é `$result = $conexao->query($sql) or die($conexao->error);`

Comment: Show amigo, era isso mesmo. Problema era que no nome do banco de dados estava sis_clientes e era sis_cliente, obrigado. Meu voto é seu. Coloca sua resposta que irei adiciona o voto, como concluído.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro acontece quando há um erro na *query*.

O método `query` da extensão `MySQLi`, pode retornar 3 resultados:

- `false`: Em caso de falha, por exempo, quando a *query* é inválida;
- `MySQLi_Result`: Em caso de sucesso para as *queries* do tipo `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE` ou `EXPLAIN`;
- `true`: Em caso de sucesso para as *queries* diferentes das citadas no item anterior, por exemplo, `insert` e `update`.

Quando utilizamos uma *query* válida, porém, com o nome da tabela ou campos diferentes, o método `query` nos retorna um `false` e por isso não conseguimos acessar a propriedade como `num_rows`.

Por isso é importante utilizarmos a verificação com `mysqli_error` ou `$conn->error`. Obviamente é necessário utilizar essa prática com cuidado. O ideal é que você armazene esses valores em um *log* e trate a mensagem para o cliente, por exemplo:

```
<?php

$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost:3307", "root", "123456", "teste");

$sql = "SHOW TABLE;"; /* Erro proposital */
$result = $conexao->query($sql);

if ($conexao->error) {
    Log::warning( $conexao->error );
    die("Não foi possível completar a operação. Entre em contato com um adminstrador do site.");
}
```

Isso evitará que pessoas má intencionadas possam obter erros de sua aplicação. Assim, somente você, desenvolvedor, saberá os erros e poderá corrigi-los em sua aplicação.